# How to deal with the interaction from a collapsed summarized list to a expand full-list?

Tags: accordion, anchors, product-details

[image]Hopefully I can explain it well, but we provide products on our website, which have a lot of product details available. But for most of the people, it's mainly about the key features. And as we have a lot of other important information available, we don't want to clutter the user experience with the full list until it's necessary for users.

So, I want to show a summarised / highlighted version of the product details and provide a clickthrough towards the full list of product details. On mobile, this is easy to solve, with a modal/dialog-view for the full-list popping-up, but on desktop, I'm not sure what's the best practice.

As of now, I have the following options in mind:
1. Highlighted features with a CTA that anchor-links down the page for the full-list.
-- This has the benefit that you can create structure in both components, but anchor-linking is generally not something that users expect or like (assumption)

2. Show highlighted features with an expand CTA that expands the component into the full list.
   -- Keeps the user at the current position, but can create discrepancy between the collapsed & expanded version

Does anybody know any best practices for this kind of behaviour on large viewports? It's sort of an accordion, in which you already show highlighted aspects of the content within in collapsed view.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or wireframe?

Comment: For some reason i can't get the wireframing tool of stack exchange to work, but I've added a wireframe to illustrate what I mean. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: What is the purpose of your feature? Why do you want people to view more details - is it to quickly compare a product with another one, or just to have a more detailed information to guide users to a more informed decision when buying (that could potentially go on its own specific-product page)?

Comment: So it's to quickly be able to assess a product if it's suitable for you yes/no, in terms of key requirements and then after making the decision, i'm interested in this product, I want to read all the features of this product.

The product in this case is a house btw, it's for real estate, in which people have hard requirements in terms of their dream home and they have more flexible requirements as well. Next to that, there's so much information that's deemed important for users to make a decision on continuing towards planning a viewing of a home.